# VS 2010 dll .data section changed in VS 2017, searching embedded data

Tags: c++

In VS 2010 I was able to search the .data section of a built dll to find
embedded data. Now using VS 2017 I can no longer find this data, not even using a binary search. Here is what I have done in the past.

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
#define CRCMARKERLABEL _T("XXX YYY ZZ")
typedef struct CrcMarkerTag
{
    BYTE    marker[sizeof(CRCMARKERLABEL)];
    time_t  tScrambleKey;  
    DWORD   dwCrcKey;
    DWORD   dwCrc;
}CRCMARKERHOLDER;
#pragma pack(pop) 

static CRCMARKERHOLDER hold_it = {CRCMARKERLABEL,0,0L,0L};
```

Using my searching app I would go through the the sections of the dll
file looking for the .data section and search on the string "XXX YYY ZZ".

If I read the dll into VS as a binary I can search for the string and see it in the VS 2010 generated dll but I can not find it in the 2017 generated dll.

This is all done using 32 bit code. I do not want this as a binary resource only to make it hard to find as it's used for security reasons.

I assume the 2017 version is compressing data or doing something else to generate the dll. Wondering if there is a way to "wrap" the data to be "pure" in the dll

I appreciate any ideas
T

Comment: Are you referencing this anywhere in your dll? is it just optimized out?

Comment: @Borgleader Even if the static struct is referenced, why would the string have to appear in the code if it's only used for its size?

Comment: @Voo It is also used to initialize `hold_it`

Comment: @VTT Ah I completely misread the code on my phone, it's actually not that crazy.

Comment: Borgleader hit the nail on the head. There was no reference in the actual DLL, after adding one it is there.